# How can I put a bit mask on /dev/zero so that I can get bytes other than zero?

Tags: devices

How can I put a bit mask on `/dev/zero` so that I can have a source not only for 0x00 but also for any byte between 0x01 and 0xFF?

Comment: Why do you ask? Please edit the question to motivate it.

Comment: You can use this answer as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634503/how-to-use-xor-in-bash

Comment: I gave an answer to this question, but reading it again I think I missunderstood it. Do you want to translate each `0x00` to a specific value or to a random value in the `0x00-0xFF` range?

Comment: @kos each to a specific value like `444444...` not a random one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following `bash` code is set to work with the byte being representred in *binary*. However you can easily change it to handle *ocatal*, *decimal* or *hex* by simply changing the *radix* `r`  value of `2`  to `8`, `10` or `16` respectively and setting `b=` accordingly.

```
r=2; b=01111110
printf -vo '\\%o' "$(($r#$b))"; </dev/zero tr '\0' "$o"
```

**EDIT** - It does handle the *full range* of byte values: *hex* **00**-**FF** (when I wrote 00-7F below, I was considering only single-byte UTF-8 characters).

If, for example, you only want 4 bytes *<s>(characters in the UTF-8 'ASCII'-only hex 00-7F range)</s>*, you can pipe it into *head*: `... | head -c4`

Output (4 chars):

```
~~~~
```

To see the output in 8-bit format, pipe it into `xxd` (or any other *1's and 0's* byte dump*):
 eg. `b=10000000` and piping to: `... | head -c4 | xxd -b`

```
0000000: 10000000 10000000 10000000 10000000                    ....
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `o=$(printf ...)` for the second line?

Comment: @jwodder: No, the second line is correct as shown. The *printf* option `-v` causes tthe output to directly set the variable named immediately after it; in this case that variable's name is `o` (for *octal*) - note that the `-v` option applies to the *shell-builtin* version of `printf` (not to the */usr/bin/printf* version)

Comment: @jwodder Also, in general, the `-v` option makes sure the variable gets set to *exactly* what you specified. `$(...)` transforms the output first. Which is why `o=$(printf '\n')` won't have the effect you might expect, whereas `printf -vo '\n'` does. (It doesn't matter here, since the output here is in a form that is unaffected by such a transformation, but if you were unaware of the `-v` option, then this might be useful to know.)

Answer (score 18):

You cannot easily do that.

You might consider writing your own kernel module providing such a device. I don't recommend that.

You could write a tiny C program writing an infinite stream of same bytes on some pipe (or on `stdout`) or FIFO.

You could use [tr(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) to read from `/dev/zero` and translate every 0 byte to somethng else.

You could use perhaps [yes(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html), at least if you can afford having newlines (or else pipe it into `tr -d '\n'`...)

Comment: Or use `yes 1 | tr -d $'\n'` for that matter.

Comment: @kojiro: that will fail if you try to `yes` a stream of `\n` chars. An alternative which handles `\n` is: `yes '' | tr '\n' "$c"` – where `$c` can be any char of the full range of ASCII characters.

Comment: @Peter.O I'm not sure how you interpreted my comment to mean anything other than the literal, static expression `yes 1 | tr -d $'\n'`. I suppose you could use a shell that doesn't do the `$''` backslash treatment, or you could try to find a locale that alters `tr -d $'\n'`, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @kojiro: Your `yes 1 | tr -d $'\n'` will quite happily print a stream of `1` characters and almost every other single-byte value, but it cannot print a stream of `\n` characters. The OP wants to be able to handle all byte values *"between 0x01 and 0xFF"*

Comment: `loop() { if [ "$1" = $'\n' ]; then yes "$1"; else yes "$1" | tr -d $'\n' ;  fi; `

Comment: @PSkocik: as mentioned in my first comment, `yes '' | tr '\n' "$c"` will work fine, for *all* byte values -- Your *`if`* version,  will put out two `\n`'s for each `\0` (that may, or may not be a problem)

Comment: @Peter.O Yup. I figured infinity times 2 was still infinity. But I'm not wedded to it.

Answer (score 13):

Well, if you *literally* want to achieve this, you can use a [LD_PRELOAD hook](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/). The basic idea is to rewrite a function from the C library and use it instead of the normal one.

Here is a simple example where we override the *read()* function to XOR the output buffer with 0x42.

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

static int dev_zero_fd = -1;

int open64(const char *pathname, int flags)
{
    static int (*true_open64)(const char*, int) = NULL;
    if (true_open64 == NULL) {
        if ((true_open64 = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open64")) == NULL) {
            perror("dlsym");
            return -1;
        }        
    }
    int ret = true_open64(pathname, flags);
    if (strcmp(pathname, "/dev/zero") == 0) {
        dev_zero_fd = ret;
    }
    return ret;
}


ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static ssize_t (*true_read)(int, void*, size_t) = NULL;
    if (true_read == NULL) {
        if ((true_read = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read")) == NULL) {
            perror("dlsym");
            return -1;
        }        
    }    

    if (fd == dev_zero_fd) {
        int i;
        ssize_t ret = true_read(fd, buf, count);    
        for (i = 0; i < ret; i++) {
            *((char*)buf + i) ^= 0x42;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    return true_read(fd, buf, count);    
}
```

A naive implementation would XOR 0x42 on every file we read, which would have undesirable consequences. In order to solve this problem, I also hooked the *open()* function, making it fetch the file descriptor associated with /dev/zero. Then, we only perform the XOR in on our *read()* function if `fd == dev_zero_fd`.

Usage:

```
$ gcc hook.c -ldl -shared -o hook.so
$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/hook.so bash #this spawns a hooked shell
$ cat /dev/zero
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Given your implementation, you could have a symbolic link from from /dev/capbee to  /dev/zero, search for /dev/capbee and leave /dev/zero alone. //dev/zero won't bee the same as /dev/zero.

Comment: @RobertJacobs Indeed. We could even generate symlinks /dev/0x01, /dev/0x02, /dev/0x03, ... to /dev/zero and parse the filename to determine the bitmask to apply.

Answer (score 11):

In terms of speed, the fastest I found was:

```
$ PERLIO=:unix perl -e '$s="\1" x 65536; for(;;){print $s}' | pv -a > /dev/null
[4.02GiB/s]
```

For comparison:

```
$ tr '\0' '\1' < /dev/zero | pv -a > /dev/null
[ 765MiB/s]
$ busybox tr '\0' '\1' < /dev/zero | pv -a > /dev/null
[ 399MiB/s]
```

```
$ yes $'\1' | tr -d '\n' | pv -a > /dev/null
[26.7MiB/s]
```

```
$ dash -c 'while : ; do echo -n "\1"; done' | pv -a > /dev/null
[ 225KiB/s]
```




```
$ bash -c 'while : ; do echo -ne "\1"; done' | pv -a > /dev/null
[ 180KiB/s]
```

```
$ < /dev/zero pv -a > /dev/null
[5.56GiB/s]
$ cat /dev/zero | pv -a > /dev/null
[2.82GiB/s]
```

Comment: In my Debian, `perl` yield 2.13GiB, while `< /dev/zero` yield 8.73GiB. What thing can affect the performance?

Comment: @cuonglm, yes, I see some variation between systems, but `perl` is consistently faster than the other solutions. I get the same throughput as with the equivalent compiled C program. The benchmark is as much on the application as on the system's scheduler here. What makes the most different is the size of the buffers being written.

Comment: @cuonglm The pipe slows it down too. I think `cat /dev/zero| pv -a >/dev/null` will give you about 2 GiBs per second too (it does on my system, while `< /dev/zero`) gives me around 6GiBps.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas May I ask what system are you on, Stéphane Chazelas? The results on mine quite differ (I can get about 2.1GiB out of the perl version). I'm on `Linux ProBook 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` Intel i5 Core inside.

Comment: @PSkocik, yes. I have those timing in my answer. That's why I say it's a scheduler benchmark. In the case of a pipe, control goes back and forth between the commands in the pipeline.

Comment: @PSkocik, Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3 (2015-04-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux, Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9600  @ 2.80GHz. The newer kernel seems to make a difference (unless it's the newer perl: v5.20.2)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The same OS with yours, AMD phenon 3.0 GHz.

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of pointless to try and bitmask/xor zero bytes, isn't it?
Taking a byte and `xor`ing it with zero is a no-op.

Just create a loop that gives you the bytes you want and put it behind a pipe or named pipe.
It'll behave pretty much the same as a character device (won't waste CPU cycles when idle):

```
mkfifo pipe
while : ; do echo -n "a"; done > pipe &
```

And if you want to super-optimize it, you can use the C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  char c = argc == 1+1 ? argv[1][0] : 'y';

  char buff[BUFSIZ];
  memset(buff, c, BUFSIZ);

  for(;;){ 
    write(1, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
  }
}
```

compile & run

```
$ CFLAGS=-O3 make loop
./loop "$the_byte_you_want" > pipe
```

Performance test:

```
./loop 1 | pv -a >/dev/null
```

**2.1GB/s** on my machine (even slightly faster than `cat /dev/zero | pv -a >/dev/null`)

Comment: I originally tried using putchar in C, but it was slow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `argc == 1+1` instead of `agrc == 2`?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard To remind myself that it's 1 for the command line executable plus 1 argument. :-D

Comment: Ah. That was my guess, but wanted to make sure there wasn't some secret reason.

Comment: "Taking a byte and xoring it with zero is a no-op." This isn't true: `0 XOR X == X`.

Comment: @jacwah Effectively, XORring with 0 hasn't affected your X in any way whatsoever. That's the definition of a no-op.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I interpreted it as 0 XOR anything will always be 0. It's not pointless in this case if there for example was a `xor` command. Then one could pipe /dev/zero to XOR the bytes into anything. You might want to clarify your answer.

Comment: The point is, if you want an infinite stream of the byte `'a'`, just write `'a'` in a  loop. There's no point in XORring those `'a'`s with `'\0'`s to get `'a'`s again.

Answer (score 5):

### Read zeros, translate each zero to your pattern!

We read zero bytes out of `/dev/zero`, and use `tr` to apply a bit mask to each of the bytes by translating each zero byte:

```
$ </dev/zero tr '\000' '\176' | head -c 10
~~~~~~~~~~$
```

Octal 176 is the ascii code of `~`, so we get 10 `~`.
(The `$` at the end of the output indicates in my shell that there was no line end - it could look different for you)

So, let's create `0xFF` bytes: Hex `0xFF` is octal `0377`. The leading zero is left out for the `tr` command line; At the end, `hexdump` is used to make the output readable.

```
$ </dev/zero tr '\000' '\377' | head -c 10 | hexdump
0000000 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff               
000000a
```

You need to use the octal codes of the characters here, instead of the hexadecimal. So it's the range from `\000` to octal `\377` (same as `0xFF`).
Use `ascii -x` and `ascii -o` to get a table of the characters with hexadecimal or octal index numbers.
(For a table with decimal and hexadecimal, just `ascii`).

### Quite fast

It runs fairly fast, compared to just using the zeros: `cat /dev/zero` is only four times as fast, while it can make perfect use of IO buffering, which `tr` can not.

```
$ </dev/zero tr '\000' '\176' | pv -a >/dev/null
[ 913MB/s]

$ </dev/zero cat | pv -a >/dev/null        
[4.37GB/s]
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you want to do with the data and how flexible you want to use it.

Worst case if you need speed, you could do the same as the /dev/zero, and just compile the /dev/one, /dev/two, .. /dev/fourtytwo .. and so on devices.

In most cases it should be better to create the data directly where it is needed, so inside a program/script as a constant. With more information people could better help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Infinte printf loop**

Reeplace `\u00` with the byte you want.

`while true ; do printf "\u00" ; done | yourapp`

**C++ code:**

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
 char out=Byte;
 while(true)
 fwrite(&out,sizeof(out),1,stdout);
}
```

**Compile:** reeplace `Byte` with the value you want.

`g++ -O3 -o bin file.cpp -D Byte=0x01`

**Use**

`./bin | yourapp`