# What's the fastest way of writing 1s to a hard disk?

Tags: files, performance, binary

I'm currently writing 1s to a file using the following:

```
tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
```

But this is a really slow method when I want to fill a 500GB disk. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Usually `dd` have used in the case

Comment: Depending on why you're doing it, consider `shred`.

Comment: Just implement /dev/one, it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sobrique: I need the disk in a particular state for testing purposes.

Comment: How fast is it running? Is `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M` appreciably faster? (I know it's not the pattern you want, but that can be changed).

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208957/38906

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster to create a reasonably-sized file full of one bits, say 1MB, with something like `tr '\0' '\377' </dev/zero | dd of=allones bs=1M`. Then you could write this repeatedly, e.g. `while true; do cat allones; done >/dev/sdb`.